# What's the meaning of `MEth0/0/1`?

Tags: networking, router

What's the meaning of `MEth0/0/1`?

I use the `[Huawei]display interface brief` command for display the interfaces of Quidway AR2220, get bellow data:

```
...
GigabitEthernet0/0/22       down  down        0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/23       down  down        0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/24       down  down        0%     0%          0          0
MEth0/0/1                   down  down        0%     0%          0          0
NULL0                       up    up(s)       0%     0%          0          0
Vlanif1                     up    down        --     --          0          0
Vlanif10                    down  down        --     --          0          0
```

But I don't know what's the `MEth0/0/1` interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Management Interface**

---

Source: http://support.huawei.com/enterprise/docinforeader!loadDocument1.action?contentId=DOC0100533701&partNo=10032#dc_s_cfg_090003

> **Management Interface**
>
> Management interfaces are used to manage and configure a device. You
>   can log in to the S5700 through a management interface to configure
>   and manage the S5700. Management interfaces do not transmit service
>   data.
>
> The S5700 provides a console interface and an MEth interface as the
>   management interface.

Comment: Hi, friend. the S5700 reverse side have two possible ports is the MEth interface, I think one of them is it, one is console port, and the other named `ETH-link` , can you tell me which is ?

Comment: I'm afraid i do not know. My answer is based on a simple search. it may be worth joining the Huawei support forums for more in-depth detail to your query.

Comment: Almost certainly MEth0/0/1 is the ETH-Link port. The serial port would not appear in a 'display interface'. The serial port is a console device and only provides shell/CLI access to the machine with a serial port adapter.

Comment: @244boy I believe the last sentence quoted answers your question "a console interface **and** an MEth interface"; since you've identified one as a console port, the other is presumably the "MEth interface", which would be consistent with the letters "ETH" in the label, and presumably the shape of the socket.